# Validation, only input should be characters not numbers

Tags: java, validation, char

i have my validation to check if input is blank but how do i write a validation to also check that the input is only characters.

```
public static String getValidSt(String aSt) {
    while (isValidSt(aSt) != true) {
        aSt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Try again!");
    }

    return aSt;
}

private static boolean isValidSt(String aSt) {
    boolean result = false;

    try {
        if (aSt.length() == 2) {
            result = true;
        } else if (aSt.length() != 2) {
            result = false;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfex) {
        result = false;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: simple google search reveal that you can use `StringUtils.isAlpha()` of Apache.Commons

Answer (score 0):

What about using the static method in the [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) class:

```
private static boolean containsOnlyLetter(String input) {
  for(int i=0; i < input.length(); i++) {
     if (!Character.isLetter(input[i])) {
       return false;
     }
  }
  return true;
}
```

And please don't arbitrary catch exceptions in your code. One day one of those will catch an important one, makes it disappear and the program will fail at a later step. Debugging that will be a pain!

Comment: you're right i just wanted to be done with this, my bad.. bad form.

Comment: i tired this but not my boolean to check if the input is blank doesnt work

Comment: That's because the method does only check if it contains only letters. It doesn't check for an empty string. Your custom condition should combine those checks - but it's a good practice to seperate concerns - so I wouldn't include it here.

Comment: how do i write another private static boolean to catch the blank input when i need to use the same .getvalidSt in my App class for both validations?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Guava `CharMatcher` class:

```
CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER.matchesAll( string )
```

Comment: not sure where i would implement that though. Still new to java

Comment: while(!CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER.matchesAll(aSt))